# How to view my recently deleted posts by moderators?

Tags: feature-request

Many of my old answers are being deleted by mods within few past days. But I receive no notification about them. some times accidentally I see them deleted. they deleted without at lest leaving a comment for notifying the author. some of them has no comment at all from other users.

But why they are not seen in my Deleted Recent Answers?

This list shows only deleted answers that are posted recently. is it possible to see the recently deleted posts regardless of the time they are posted?

Comment: did any SE manager see this question?